# Using DatePickerDialog's manual input mode

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, android-datepicker

According to Google, I should use a [manual input mode](https://storage.googleapis.com/spec-host/mio-staging%2Fmio-components%2F1566425689922%2Fassets%2F1wNxz6MUqYsaFugCBe80ekoVz6m1XsS2K%2Fpicker-choosing-textfield.png) when querying the user about their date of birth or querying about dates that doesn't require the Calendar View, but I can't find any way to use it in `Xamarin.Android`.
I have already tried setting `DatePicker.DatePicker.CalendarViewShown` and `DatePicker.DatePicker.SpinnersShown` off and on respectively but both are marked as deprecated and don't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a DatePickerDialog which entends `DialogFragment`.
I created a simple demo to simulate the function.

The main code is:

class DatePickerDialogFragment

```
public class DatePickerDialogFragment: DialogFragment
{
    private readonly Context _context;
    private DateTime _date;
    private readonly DatePickerDialog.IOnDateSetListener _listener;
    public DatePickerDialogFragment(Context context, DateTime date, DatePickerDialog.IOnDateSetListener listener)
    {
        _context = context;
        _date = date;
        _listener = listener;
    }
    public override Dialog OnCreateDialog(Bundle savedState)
    {
        var dialog = new DatePickerDialog(_context, _listener, _date.Year, _date.Month - 1, _date.Day);
        return dialog;
    }
}
```

activity_main.axml

```
<EditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/editTextCalender"
          android:hint="Enter date"
/>
```

MainActivity.cs

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity, 
Android.App.DatePickerDialog.IOnDateSetListener
{
    private EditText editCalender;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        editCalender = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editTextCalender);
        editCalender.Click += DateSelect_OnClick;
    }

    private void DateSelect_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var dialog = new DatePickerDialogFragment(this, DateTime.Now, this);
        dialog.Show(FragmentManager, "date");
    }

    public void OnDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth)
    {
        var date = new DateTime(year, month + 1, dayOfMonth);
        editCalender.Text = date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
    }
}
```

**Update:**
Then you can use `Regular Expressions` to Match  the input date string.

For example:

```
  string date = edit.Text.Trim().ToString();
  string pattern = "^(?<year>\\d{2,4})/(?<month>\\d{1,2})/(?<day>\\d{1,2})$"; //yyyy/MM/dd

  bool match = false;
  match = Regex.IsMatch(date, pattern);

  if (!match)
   {
     edit.Text = "";
     Toast.MakeText(this, "The input format is incorrect.", ToastLength.Short).Show();
     }
     else
     {
      Toast.MakeText(this, "The input format is correct.", ToastLength.Short).Show();
     }
```

Comment: That is not the desired behaviour. Instead of calendar view, I want manual input mode, like this: https://storage.googleapis.com/spec-host/mio-staging%2Fmio-components%2F1566425689922%2Fassets%2F1wNxz6MUqYsaFugCBe80ekoVz6m1XsS2K%2Fpicker-choosing-textfield.png